# Partition Time Machine volume already used

Tags: macos, time-machine, partition

I want to partition/reduce size my Time Machine volume to use it also with another Mac.
Now I've this situation
[image]

I want to change the partition and do this
[image]

But the two tips of the partitions says

--- one

[image]

--- the other one

[image]

What will happen to the files if I apply this partitions?
Will I lose all the old Time Machine backup files?

Answer (score 1):

All the files currently located within the partition 'Time Machine' will be located in the partition 'Time Machine 1'. The partition 'Time Machine 2' will be empty and no files will be deleted.

Disk Utility should prompt you if the contents of Time Machine doesn't fit in Time Machine 1, but to be safe, check first.